# Geocoder Class Explanation

Tags: android, reverse-geocoding

Can anyone tell me how reverse geocoder works. I have code which uses getFromlocation and getLastKnownLocation to find out the address. The thing is i don't know how to use the OnLocationChanged on it and how to disable the listener when i dont need it. I am utterly confused for the past 2 days. If any one can provide me some good resources with complete examples or link it would be great..

```
                Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(
                    TrackLogic.this.getApplicationContext(),
                    Locale.getDefault());
            Location locationGPS = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Location locationNetwork = locationManager
                    .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            Log.d(TAG, "geocoder works");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get a LocationManager instance and the name of the provider you want to use to do a location look-up.  For example:

```
String provider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Next, you call requestLocationUpdates(...) like so:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 1000, 0, this);
```

This can be invoked on the main thread since (I think) the system will do the location lookup using the specified provider on a background thread.  When a location is found, the Android system will invoke the onLocationChanged(...) callback, which you need to override. Since you're trying to do an address lookup, you would put in:

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this);
geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 10)
```

which should get you what you're looking for.

When you're done with using the Location services, you can call

```
locationManager.removeUpdates(this)
```

Comment: what happens if i use locationManager.getLastKnownLocation along with the geocoder.getFromLocation?

Comment: I don't know. I've only used getFromLocation().  I would think that the results of getFromLocation() would override whatever is is getLastKnownLocation().  What're you using this API for?

Comment: I am trying to retrieve the users location when he clicks a button. But i keep getting weird response. Sometimes it returns null and stuff.

Comment: What returns null?  getLastKnownLocation() can return null if the location provider isn't enabled.  One thing you can try doing before using the location service is to iterate through each of the providers and call isProviderEnabled()

Comment: It turns out the location provider didnt return anything..thats why it was null. I had one doubt though.. My code display the address correctly during the first try. It displays the address which was last stored